# x increases with 125% each week, what is x week n?

Tags: exponential-function

`x` has the value `1`.

How would I calculate the accumulative value of `x` for a certain week, if `x` increases with 125% each week?

Comment: 1.25, and the following week 1.56. Could I have expressed it better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of first week, $x$ becomes $1.25$

At the end of second week, $x$ becomes $1.25^2$

At the end of third week, $x$ becomes $1.25^3$

In general, at the end of $n^{th}$ week, $x$ becomes $1.25^n$

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but is this possible to calculate with a simple calculator (like the one in an iPhone)?

Comment: @Numbers On an actual pocket calculator (the ones that might be driven by a solar panel) you do it by typing `1.25`, and then the multiplication button $n$ times. A calculator app should have an advanced panel. On that panel, look for a button with something like `^`, `x^y` or $x^y$ written on it.

Comment: Also, a $125\%$ increase probably means that the factor is $2.25$ instead of $1.25$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Calculate the amount that $x$ increases in week one, two, three and maybe four. Try to see a pattern in terms of an exponent that reflects which week you are in. Once you have that pattern, generalize the answer in terms of $n$.